# How to create a random video player with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I want to create a video player with javascript/css/html only and have a randomly selected video play.

See comments below for link to sample codepen code

Comment: It would NOT be possible to solve your problem without code. Maybe you could reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: What did you do? Created an account and without looking at anything at all, asked a question? Do you even know what's the purpose of this website? Please visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmPym I edit a little bit the code for my computer all video don't run on yours i think

Comment: the first link in the sample is a 404, and the third is a zip file which can't play in a <video> element

Answer (score 1):

Based on a simplified version of your codepen, and just answering the 'how to select and play a random video' question see below.

I have used jQuery for this (which requires the slightly convoluted method to call `play` on the DOM element) but that was what you used in your sample

```
<video id="video" muted controls width=200 height=180></video>
<ul id="playlist">
<li><a href="video-number1.mp4">Number One</a>
<li><a href="video-number2.mp4">Number Two</a>
<li><a href="video-number3.mp4">Number Three</a>
</ul>

<script>
    // Get the playlist from the available URLs on the list 
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    // Select a random item from the list...
    vid = Math.round(Math.random()*len);
    // ... and get the href
    vidURL = tracks[vid].href;

    //console.log(vid + " " + vidURL)
    // Set the source to the selected URL
    $("#video").get(0).src = vidURL
    // Play the selected URL
    $("#video").get(0).play();

</script>
```